# sort database field partially

Tags: database, sorting, field

I need to sort a field "name" of that contains some name, NULL and few blank records. Somehow i need to sort them by arranging all the name in alphabetical sort order at the top and after that all rows containing NULL should come and after that all rows containing blank should come. For example my table is

```
id   Name
1    NULL
2    NULL
3    
4    
5    Mobile
6    Apparel 
7    Shoes
```

So the result should be like

```
6    Apparel    
5    Mobile
7    Shoes
1    NULL
2    NULL
3    
4
```

There can be thousand of rows in this format so i don't know how many null as well as blank rows are there. The above example is just a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Name 
FROM
(
 SELECT
   CASE 
     WHEN Name IS NULL THEN 1
     WHEN Name = '' THEN 2
     ELSE 0 END
   Sorter,
   Name
 FROM YourTable
) t
ORDER BY Sorter, Name
```

Or without subselect:

```
SELECT Name
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY
  CASE 
    WHEN Name IS NULL THEN 1
    WHEN Name = '' THEN 2
    ELSE 0 
  END,
  Name
```

Comment: I upvoted but dont know why it dont let me accepting answer..But surely do that.